# I want to expose the time it took from start of 1 method to the end of another method to Prometheus

Tags: performance, prometheus, metrics

I want to expose the time it took from when an event enters a method (its a rest endpoint), to the end of another method thats in a completely different class (a rabbit MQ publisher), to measure the processing time of 1 event in my app, and want to expose this time to prometheus. Is this somehow possible ?

A simple thought process:

External source -> sends event -> Arrives in my app -> start mesuring time -> processing of the event -> event is published to rabbit -> stop measuring time  (i wanna see this time in ms in prometheus)

Comment: This isn't really a good use case for Prometheus. Distributed tracing with Zipkin/Jaeger already do this

Comment: Otherwise, you need to generate a timestamp at the client side (`requestedAt`), at the server, `receivedAt`, `sentAt` to the queue, then another `receivedAt = now()` at the consumer side, then process the difference...

Comment: I believe it could be a little bit simpler than what OneCricketeer described, basically you'll need to "drag" timestamp of beginning through your code, and use it at the end to create metric. But Prometheus is not really designed to store such a data (unless you are planning to expose it as histogram).

Comment: Would you consider using ThreadLocal? If so I can provide a solution.

Comment: @markalex Yes. What I described was "dragging" - the API server and/or queue producer creates a timestamp, which the consumer later reads, and calculates the difference. [Spring Cloud Slueth](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/) can do this for RabbitMQ, but uses traces, as mentioned, not Prometheus